# Server solution, forwarding HTTP traffic

Tags: http, http-proxy, wireshark

I'm looking for a solution to redirect GET/POST HTTP requests on a server.

The easy part would be port translation and hostname redirection (HTTP 3xx redirection):
When my server in a DMZ receives traffic on port 7070 (http://mydmz.server.com:7070), it would redirect the traffic to a public web server (http://liveupdate.symantecliveupdate.com on default port 80)

But It also needs to modify on the fly request headers:

- **/clu-prod** should get stripped from the URI
- **Host: mydmz.server.com** should be replaced by **Host: liveupdate.symantecliveupdate.com**

What tool, solutions could I use on a server to listen on port 7070 and do the following ? A load balancer, a HTTP proxy ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve this with HAProxy.

- Set it to listen port 7070/tcp in httpd mode.
- modify host header with haproxy replace-value. In your case it could be like:

  ```
  http-request replace-value Host mydmz.server.com:(.*) liveupdate.symantecliveupdate.com:\1
  ```
- strip URI with haproxy url rewriting. In you case this could be something like:

  ```
  reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)clu-prod[/]?(.*)     \1\2
  ```

With those settings your HAProxy configuration could look something like this (this is quickly modified from HAProxy default config in CentOS 7, this is **not** tested thoroughly):

```
    global
   log         127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend  main *:7070
    default_backend             app

backend app
    http-request replace-value Host mydmz.server.com:(.*) liveupdate.symantecliveupdate.com:\2
    reqrep ^(.*)/clu-prod(.*) \1/\2
    balance     roundrobin
    server  app1 liveupdate.symantecliveupdate.com:80 check
```

Other option you maybe could use is squid proxy http://www.squid-cache.org/